# Linear estimation of an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, estimation, means

QUESTION

We have $Y \sim \mathrm{Exp}(1/6)$. We define $T = e^{−4Y}$

Calculate the best linear estimator of $T$ according to $Y$

ANSWER

Ok it sounds pretty simple at first

I got my $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{6} \cdot e^{-\frac{y}{6}}$.

I am pretty sure the equation for an estimation is $g(Y)=E[T\mid Y]$

First i need the density function of $T$ given $Y$ : $h(t\mid y)=\frac{f(y,t)}{f_Y(y)}$. Then, $E(T\mid Y)=\int t\cdot h(t\mid y) \, dt$

I have $f_Y(y)$ , but how i find $f(y,t)$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note: $\mathsf E(e^{-4Y}\mid Y) = e^{-4Y}$

Comment: Your "equation for an estimation" won't work for your purpose because it is not linear as a function of $Y$ (and by "linear" I suspect you mean simply $a+bY$, so that the graph as a function of $Y$  is a straight line). $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, but they ask me to find the most accurate linear estimation, $g(Y)=aY+b$ to estimate $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I'll guess that by "linear" you mean an estimator of the form $a+bY$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants, i.e. are not random.  (But maybe one could also mean just $bY$, without the $a$?)

"Best" is sometimes taken to mean minimizing the expected square of the residual $T - (a+bY)$, i.e. choose $a$ and $b$ to make
$$
\operatorname{E}\Big( ( T - (a+bY) )^2 \Big)
$$
as small as possible.  So compute the expected value:
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{E}\Big( ( T - (a+bY) )^2 \Big) = \int_0^\infty \left( e^{-4y} - (a+by) \right)^2 e^{-y/6} \, \frac{dy} 6 \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^\infty \left(  e^{-8y} +a^2 + b^2y^2 - 2ae^{-4y} - 2by e^{-4y} + 2aby \right) e^{-y/6} \, \frac{dy} 6.
\end{align}
To evaluate this, recall that
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-ry}\,dy & = \frac 1 r \\[10pt]
\int_0^\infty y e^{-ry}\,dy & = \frac 1 {r^2} \\[10pt]
\int_0^\infty y^2 e^{-ry} \, dy & = \frac 2 {r^3}
\end{align}
When you're done, you'll have a quadratic function of $a$ and $b$.  You need to find the value of $(a,b)$ that minimizes it.

Comment: It gives me 2 pairs of coordinates with the same error of 1.

$a=\frac{-4}{625}-\frac{\sqrt{(18 808 849)}}{(26 250)}$     ,    $b=\frac{49}{625}+\frac{\sqrt{(18 808 849)}}{(4375)}$

and 

$a=\frac{-4}{625}+\frac{\sqrt{(18 808 849)}}{(26 250)}$     ,    $b=\frac{49}{625}-\frac{\sqrt{(18 808 849)}}{(4375)}$

Comment: Here's what I've got so far: $$\int_0^\infty \left(  e^{-8y} +a^2 + b^2y^2 - 2ae^{-4y} - 2by e^{-4y} + 2aby \right) e^{-y/6} \, \frac{dy} 6 $$ $$ = \text{constant} + a^2 + 72 b^2 - \frac 2 {25} a - \frac{12}{625} b + 12 ab = g(a,b).$$ (where "constant" means not depending on $(a,b)$).  Then $$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial a} = 2a - \frac 2 {25} + 12b, $$ $$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial b} = 144b - \frac{12}{625} + 12 a. $$ These two partial derivatives are $0$ if $a=\dfrac{49}{25}$ and $b= \dfrac{-4}{625}$. $\qquad$